# my app keeps getting slower in Angular.js?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have an application made in ionic, it has several sections. It has a section that the first time is used download a dataset of 18,000 records (using $ http requests) and stored in a local database (pouchdb). then I get these 18 000 records and gender cycles for certain operations I need.

the problem is that whenever I access this section, this will gradually becoming slower. in the application settings (app.js) I have the option

{Cache: false}

in all routes of my app.

with this is supposed to release memory, I do not understand why gradually becomes increasingly slow.
the way I have my project with controllers and data in html views.
every time I go to this section I get the 18 thousand records and perform operations. It is necessary to cover all these 18 000 records each time I log. for example I have the list of all the cities of my country, someone selected from a dropdown a city and then I walk all records for operations, then it is necessary. more or less is what I have.

This only happens when I compile for android devices. but I have a samsung galaxy s7 and does not occur this problem, always fast. which makes me think it may be a ram problem.
What I can do?

I have an application made in ionic, it has several sections. It has a section that the first time is used download a dataset of 18,000 records (using $ http requests) and stored in a local database (pouchdb). then I get these 18 000 records and gender cycles for certain operations I need.

the problem is that whenever I access this section, this will gradually becoming slower. in the application settings (app.js) I have the option

{Cache: false}

in all routes of my app.

with this is supposed to release memory, I do not understand why gradually becomes increasingly slow. the way I have my project with controllers and data in html views. every time I go to this section I get the 18 thousand records and perform operations. It is necessary to cover all these 18 000 records each time I log. for example I have the list of all the cities of my country, someone selected from a dropdown a city and then I walk all records for operations, then it is necessary. more or less is what I have.

This only happens when I compile for android devices. but I have a samsung galaxy s7 and does not occur this problem, always fast. which makes me think it may be a ram problem. What I can do?

Comment: Maybe do some lazy loading for example (only load the part you need, i doubt you will always need 18000 record in the memory)

Comment: Did not read the whole post but if app gets slower over time them you might have a memory leak. Do some research about how to detect those using dev tools.

Comment: @HarryLim is necesary load all the records...then i need find in the 18 records,i need..